Connectivity between two switches
We have existing setup of manageable juniper switches with two vlans, one for door access and other for the CCTV. One of our switch gets faulty. Could I add unmanageable (Ubiquity) (plug and play ) switch instead?
I have connected two switches with fiber optic SPF TO SFP. But there is no pinging between switches.

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

An unmanaged switch doesn't separate VLANs, so no, that won't do.
Separating VLANs/segments using unmanaged switches requires that you don't connect them at all. You can't used tagged VLANs either.

Thanks for your reply. The switch (Ubiquiti 24 PoE 500W) I want to add is manageable. But the thing is I don't have a controller to manage the switch. The only option for the controller is my PC. Through PC I tried to create VLAN by using the Unifi network application but I couldn't assign a IP. Notification appear says that I need a third party gateway or OS Console.

Usually, there's a management console or at least a web GUI - but how do I configure ... is another question. However, devices without optional, paid vendor support are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].
